# not able to deploy flink application

Tags: docker, apache-flink, kubectl

I have developed the Java Flink code, which I want to deploy as docker image and test that as jobManager and TaskManager yamls to run the application up and running. But I am facing the issues to make the service up and running. I have followed [these steps](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2019/08/24/deploy-flink-job-cluster-on-kubernetes/) to deploy the code in kubernates.

getting below errors,

> C:\Deployment\Flink>kubectl apply -f Flink-JobManager.yaml
>   The Job "flink-on-kubernetes-jobmanager" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"job-name":"flink-on-kubernetes-jobmanager", "app":"flink", "controller-uid":"bb738bd8-1729-11ea-8e51-7acc0f0eb42c", "instance":"flink-on-kubernetes-jobmanager"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"jobmanager", Image:"flink-on-kubernetes:0.0.1", Command:[]string{"/opt/flink/bin/standalone-job.sh"}, Args:[]string{"start-foreground", "-Djobmanager.rpc.address=flink-on-kubernetes-jobmanager", "-Dparallelism.default=1", "-Dblob.server.port=6124", "-Dqueryable-state.server.ports=6125"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort{core.ContainerPort{Name:"rpc", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:6123, Protocol:"TCP", HostIP:""}, core.ContainerPort{Name:"blob", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:6124, Protocol:"TCP", HostIP:""}, core.ContainerPort{Name:"query", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:6125, Protocol:"TCP", HostIP:""}, core.ContainerPort{Name:"ui", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:8081, Protocol:"TCP", HostIP:""}}, EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar(nil), Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"Always", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, RestartPolicy:"OnFailure", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc00ba42298), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:"", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc005751650), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil)}}: field is immutable

Comment: I'm quite sure you need to include JobManager.yaml for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: @JamesZ is quite right there. This seems to be related to the Kubernetes.

Comment: Please attach the content of `Flink-JobManager.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to modify an immutable field in your deployment. Adding labels to spec.template.metadata.labels (apart from the ones set in the deployment matching labels, e.g. "app" and "component") would lead to this error, for example.

You can (a) delete the deployment and re-deploy or (b) identify and remove the property/properties that break re-deployment.